# React Material-UI Chip's onDelete inside Select is not working

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I followed the Chips example here, in order to render chips as the renderValue of the Select:

https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

However, when I added onDelete to the chip, in order to delete the chip in one click, I can see the close icon, but **the delete event is not invoked** (because the menu of Select shows).

```js
<Select
        multiple
        value={selectedProducts}
        onChange={handleProductsSearchChange}
        renderValue={selected => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
            {selected.map(value => (
                <Chip key={value} label={find(FAKE_PRODUCTS, {id: value}).name}
                        onDelete={() => handleDeleteSearchProduct(value)} 
                        className={classes.chip} />
                ))}
            </div>)}
        MenuProps={{ PaperProps: {
            style: {
                maxHeight: 48 * 4.5 + 8,
                width: 250,
            }
        }
}}
>
{menuItems}
</Select>
```

When I put the chip outside of the select, the delete event is invoked.
What do you think I can do in order to prevent the behaviour of the menu opening on click?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the select click handler have functionality that directly contradicts the behavior of chip deletion?

Comment: Not that I know of.. It seems like when clicking the delete icon, the menu catches the click event and ignores it, and only opens the select menu.

Comment: That's very strange that it completely omits the click. Usually the issue is that the click handler on the chip fires but the select menu fires as well. That's easily fixable with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Exactly, I know how to handle the case in which both of the components catch the event. but it seems that menu blocks the click action

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`Select` component intercepts `mousedown` event, so add

```
onMouseDown={(event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
}}
```

to your `Chip` component.

Comment: this does the trick, thanks. Notice this pb may have to be reported on material-ui tracker, it used to work.

Comment: It works, but I don't like it :/ such is life I guess

Comment: This does the trick. However, I'm having some trouble with the Select not loosing focus when clicking outside of it. Any suggestion on how to fix that?

Comment: I tried all permutations of stopPropagation and preventDefault in both event handlers and settled on the following so that the focus highlight does not get stuck.

```javascript
onMouseDown={(event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}}
onDelete={(event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
}}
```

Comment: For posterity, first time in months that an answer on SO was more insightful than the one given to me by ChatGPT

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works, stop propagation in chip component

```
onMouseDown={(event) => {
 event.stopPropagation();
}}
```

for continue the focus in select can create a referency
`selectRef = React.createRef();` and call `selectRef.current.focus();` its resets the focus to the component